# What prevents a needy from stealing and being sold into slavery?

Tags: halacha-theory, slave-serve-eved-avadim, parshanut-theory

Imagine a poor Jewish guy with a screaming wife and 12 little kids that went bankrupt and lost everything he had. He still needs to support himself and his family.

What prevents him from selecting the path of theft and the following slavery that ensures his and his family a master-level of provision for at least 6 years?

Comment: אִם־כֶּ֣סֶף ׀ תַּלְוֶ֣ה אֶת־עַמִּ֗י אֶת־הֶֽעָנִי֙ עִמָּ֔ךְ לֹֽא־תִהְיֶ֥ה ל֖וֹ כְּנֹשֶׁ֑ה לֹֽא־תְשִׂימ֥וּן עָלָ֖יו נֶֽשֶׁךְ׃ http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0222.htm#24

Comment: @Kazibácsi ?? What's the relation to the question?

Comment: @AlBerko He can sell himself because of poverty and avoid the sin of stealing.

Comment: Someone has to be willing to buy him,and as you mentioned in another question, "who would want to acquire a master ".

Comment: @Al If you see your fellow Jews in such a dire financial situation, you should give a loan without interest and/or _tzedakah_

Comment: @sabbahillel right, but then he misses the perk - a shiktze! So what's to lose?

Comment: @Kazibácsi I completely agree, that's why I suggest his steal might be seen as a Tzedaka in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

God said not to steal. That stops most people.

Also, he can't be sold unless there's a willing buyer. Buyers seeing the added expense will presumably not buy him (or not at the same price as without the added expense).